# Inputting data row by row from a large data set into a hypertable (Postgre)

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a csv file with 5 columns of data and 5000+ rows. My task is to input the data ONE by ONE into a hypertable which I already created.

My question is : the COPY function copies the entire file into the hypertable. I could just sit and  use the INPUT function and input the data one by one - however, this is very painful and very time consuming.

I'm not sure how the conditional loops work, the documentation available is a little hazy. I have experience in C and python if that helps.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Why is it necessary to do it one row at a time? Using `COPY` would be the most efficient way.  If you insist on doing it the hard way then see [Python csv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#module-csv) and the csv.reader example. Use [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) as the Python driver to `INSERT` the data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it has been very clearly specified in my task that I HAVE to input it one by one. This is a fairly new field for me, and we have to specifically use only the available functions (no python or any other external program) to do it.  I was thinking of maybe using a for or while loop. If so, how would I use a for loop for this case?

Comment: What available functions? Please add response(and previous response) as update to question.  The more information you can provide the better the chance you get an answer. If it where me I would `COPY` the data to a staging table and then use a [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)  function to `INSERT` from there to the hypertable using a [Loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

Comment: Have you tried the timescale python getting started? maybe it can help: https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/quick-start/python/

also, this episode shows how to insert data from a CSV: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLcU9uAItHk

Comment: Where does the requirement *one by one* come from. You should ask that source to explain - they perhaps do not mean the same by that as you do. Could they mean that each must independently exist when your finished as opposed to a summarized version?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver im very new to this forum so im not sure how to add comments as an update to the question.  I believe I need to use the INSERT function in a loop and import the data into the table.

Comment: @Belayer Thank you for the response. What it means is that, instead of using copy, which transfers data through the bulk, I have to import the rows one by one. So like, row1, then row2.....row5k. I believe I need to use a WHILE/FOR loop and then use an INSERT in that and input the data. Could you perhaps point me in the right way to use a conditional and an INSERT in the same way? I tried using a WHILE loop and used a counter variable for each row, and as it increased, i used the "INSERT FROM " " INTO "table" . Im not sure if thats right though, any advice is much appreciated